# subscribe queue to topic using camel route

Tags: spring, apache-camel, aws-sdk

How to subscribe queue to the topic using `apache camel` and `spring`?

I do it like this

```
amazonSNSClient.subscribe("arn:aws:sns:yopa-local:000000000000:test-topic-with-subscriptions", 
    "sqs", "arn:aws:sqs:yopa-local:000000000000:test-subscribed-queue-standard");
```

With parameters

```
endpoint -> arn:aws:sqs:yopa-local:000000000000:test-subscribed-queue-standard
protocol -> sqs
topic-arn -> arn:aws:sns:yopa-local:000000000000:test-topic-with-subscriptions
```

And it seems to work fine. But how to do it using `camel`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AWS-SNS/AWS-SQS component of Camel. Documentation: http://camel.apache.org/aws-sns.html

http://camel.apache.org/aws-sqs.html